# How to select first item in DevExpress ComboBoxEdit?

Tags: wpf, devexpress-wpf

I have WPF application and use UserControl as a view. Inside that UserControl there is DevExpress ComboBoxEdit.

```
<UserControl ... 
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="ComboBoxInspectionList" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding InspectionList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInspection}" IsTextEditable="False"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ComboBox is data bound. I've tried this:

```
public partial class InspectionList : UserControl
{
    public InspectionList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (ComboBoxInspectionList.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            ComboBoxInspectionList.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

But, data binding happened after the code in UserControl's constructor is executed.

Comment: Just set from your ViewModel's constructor something like SelectedInspection = InspectionList.FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just set the `SelectedIndex` property to 0 in the XAML markup?:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="ComboBoxInspectionList" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding InspectionList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInspection}" IsTextEditable="False"/>
```

The MVVM way of doing this would be to set the `SelectedInspection` property to an object that is actually present in the `InspectionList` in the view model as suggested by @3615:

```
SelectedInspection = InspectionList.FirstOrDefault();
```

You can obviously not select an item that is not present in the `Items` collection of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: I've tried SelectedIndex="0" in XAML, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Set the SelectedInspection source property then?

Comment: Set SelectedInspection to what and when?

Comment: Didn't you read my reply? Set it to the first item in the InspectionList collection in the constuctor of the class where it is defined.

Comment: SelectedInspection property should be set in view model, but not in constructor. It should be set after populating InspectionList. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it should be set after you have populated the InspectionList. Otherwise the item can't be present in the list. Whether to set the property in the constructor depends on where you populate the collection.